# GetImageThumbnail() with dimensions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In our ASP.NET MVC 3 We are currently generating thumbnail images on the fly with the following code:

```
public void GetImageThumbnail(string imageName)
{

   WebImage wbImage = new WebImage("~/assets/images/gallery/"+imageName+".jpg");

   int width = 220;

   wbImage.Resize(width, (int)((double)wbImage.Height * width / wbImage.Width));

   wbImage.FileName = imageName+"_small.jpg";

   wbImage.Write();

}
```

and displaying them in the view like this:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImageThumbnail", new {imageName = "motherboard"})" alt="" />
```

How can we control the image size on the view and generate the complete `<img>` tag from scratch? We need to specify the image dimension and obtain an `<img>` tag the contains the `width` and `height` properties.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is to create your own HTML helper method which does all of the work.  Something you would consume like:

```
    @Html.ThumbnailImg("motherboard")
```

That method does the thumbnail work and can output the full desired markup.  More info: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs.  For what it's worth, I prefer the extension method design.  It seems more *palatable* to other devs.

UPDATE:
There is a little bit of chicken-and-egg that I didn't think about before.  Perhaps something like:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString ThumbnailImg(
        this HtmlHelper html,
        UrlHelper url,
        String imageName,
        String elementID,
        String altText)
    {

        var img = new TagBuilder("img");
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(elementID) == false) img.MergeAttribute("id", elementID);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(altText) == false) img.MergeAttribute("alt", altText);

        // Generate and cache thumnail here, determining height and width
        // ... 

        var src = url.Action("GetImageThumbnail", new { imageName = imageName });
        img.MergeAttribute("height", height);
        img.MergeAttribute("width", width);

        img.MergeAttribute("src", src);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(img.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I call the `@Url.Action("GetImageThumbnail", new {imageName = "motherboard"})` inside the helper method?

Comment: I updated my answer with a bit of code ... if you need to know the height and width, you're going to have to generate the thumbnail first (unless you force dimensions).  You could cache that somewhere for use later (and also helps prevent having to generate the same thumbnail over and over).